# Force npm to use same version of package as one of its dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management

Is there any way to force npm to install the same version of a dependency for my app that one of my package's dependencies uses?

The situation is that I have a library of UI components which includes a time zone control. This time zone control uses moment-timezone. In my app, I use moment-timezone as well, to do some calculations on time values and whatnot.

However, I don't want the time zone metadata to get out of sync between my app and the time zone control, for obvious reasons.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I could accomplish this? Lines of attack I've either pondered or tried and why I've had issues with them:

- Have the library specify the particular version it uses as a peerDependency. The problem is that even if the app that uses the library doesn't need moment-timezone (which most won't), npm will throw a warning if the peerDependency is missing.
- Include the library's version of moment-timezone via *library*/node_modules/moment-timezone. Depending on the particular layout of directories feels pretty sketchy, though.
- Just put all the time zone manipulation code into the library. That makes sense for some of it, but some of it feels like it's too specific to my use case to warrant inclusion in the library (and possibly this just means I need to do some refactoring).

Essentially what I need is something like an optional peerDependency, which isn't a thing.

Comment: Not sure wht you mean by _However, I don't want the time zone metadata to get out of sync between my app and the time zone control_, maybe an example? In any case, if you specify the same version in your package.json as that of the library does that not solve your problem?

Comment: Oh, I can - I just don't want users of the library to have to manually make sure their apps are using the same version of moment-timezone as the library is.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you find a solution for this or keep it as a "manual" process?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this until now - unfortunately I don't recall what we ended up doing.